# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: Laravel index.php unable to access

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I know there are few questions already regarding this problem with Laravel. However, none of them solved my issue. So after installing larval with composer correctly, I have create the Laravel project folder within my htdocs. When I start my XAMPP server and try to access it via the url like

```
http://localhost/Php/myLaravel/public/index
```

I receive something a blank page or sometimes I receive this error message below.

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 533
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 512
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
```

This is fresh installation and nothing has been changed. Here is the .htaccess file from the project folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Can someone please help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I did figure it out by changing the permissions on the ./storage directory to be writable and voila it worked! Hope it helps to someone else!

Answer (score 0):

After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions.

so give permission to following two directories:

```
storage

bootstrap/cache
```

it works for me...

i hope its help you